# How to drop SRID=4326 from GeoPandas MultiPolygon Geometry column

Tags: python, dataframe, geopandas, shapefile, wkt

I am using shape data from .shp files and using geopandas to convert those into Multipolygons for my postgresql table with a column of type `geometry(multipolygon, 4326) NULL`. The issue I'm running into is I don't know how I can drop the `SRID=4326` part of the data.

For example, `SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON(((-113.82162 31.50802........`, but I just need `MULTIPOLYGON(((-113.82162 31.50802........`. I'm fairly new to GeoPandas and any help would be appreciated. Here is the necessary code.

```
gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path).to_crs(epsg=4326)
gdf['geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].apply(lambda x: MultiPolygon([x]) if isinstance(x, Polygon) else x)
gdf['geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].apply(lambda x: WKTElement(x.wkt, srid=4326))
gdf.to_sql(table_name, engine, schema='shapes', if_exists='append', index=False, method='multi', dtype={'geometry': Geometry('MULTIPOLYGON', srid=4326)})
```